# Identity sequences on the Rubik's Cube

Tags: code-golf, rubiks-cube

A move sequence is a sequence of moves (turns) on a Rubik's Cube (for the notation look down below). Beside the empty move sequence, there are many other other move sequences, that have no effect on the cube at all. We call these move sequences identity sequences.

Some of these identity sequences are obvious to determine, like `U2 R R' U2` or `U D2 U' D2`. In the first one, two random moves are done `U2 R` and afterwards immediately undone `R' U2`. The second one is similar. First two random moves `U D2` and afterwards they are undone, but in reversed order `U' D2`. This only works, because the move `U` effects only the pieces of the upper layer and the move `D2` only effects pieces of the lower layer. You can see a visualization of these two move sequences.

[image: U2 R R' U2] [image: U D2 U' D2]

Other identity sequences may be not obvious at all. For instance the sequence `R' U' R' F' U F U' R' F R F' U' R U2 R`. It pretty long, but also has no effect at the cube at all.

[image]

### Move Notation

A move describes the turn of one layer of one of the six faces of the cube. A move consist of one letter representing the face followed by an optional suffix representing the turn angle.

The letters and their corresponding faces are **U** (Up - the side facing upwards), **D** (Down - the side facing downwards), **R** (Right - the side facing to the right), **L** (Left - the side facing to the left), **F** (Front - the side facing you) and **B** (Back - the side facing away from you).

If there is no suffix, the face is turned 90-degree clockwise, the suffix **`'`** means, the face is turned 90-degree counterclockwise, and the suffix **`2`** means, the face is turned 180-degree clockwise.

It you have any problems with the notation, just use [http://alg.cubing.net](http://alg.cubing.net/), where you can visualize such move sequences.

### The Challenge

Your task is to write a program, that determines if a move sequences is an identity or not.

You may write a full program or a function. It should receive a string containing a move sequence (moves are separate by spaces) as input (via STDIN, command-line argument, prompt or function argument), and output (via return value or STDOUT) a Boolean value or a corresponding integer (True - 1 - identity sequence/ False - 0 - not identity sequence).

If you suffix `'` creates problems in your programming language, you may use a different symbol, but not at digit. `R F2 U3` is not allowed.

This is codegolf, therefore the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

### Test Cases

```
"" -> True
"U2 R R' U2" -> True
"U D2 U' D2" -> True
"U2 R U2 R'" -> False
"R' U' R' F' U F U' R' F R F' U' R U2 R" -> True
"L'" -> False
"B B2 B' B2" -> True
"D D2 D'" -> False
"R F' D2 U B' F2 B' U2 D2 F2 B2 U F R'" -> True
"D2 U' R2 U F2 D2 U' R2 U' B' L2 R' B' D2 U B2 L' D' R2" -> False
"R U R' U' R' F R2 U' R' U' R U R' F' R2 U R2 U' R2 U' D R2 U' R2 U R2 D'" -> True
"R U R' U' R' F R2 U' R' U' R U R' F' R2 U' R2 U R2 U' D R2 U' R2 U R2 D'" -> False
"B2 F2 U' F2 U R2 F2 U2 B D' R' D' R2 D' F2 U' F U R2 U R B D B D2 L2 D' F2 U D' R' D B R2 D2 F2 R' F2 D2" -> True
"R U2 R' U R' U2 R U2 R U R' U' R' U R U2" -> False
"U F B' R' U F' R U' F' B L U' F L'" -> False
"R2 U' R' U' R U R U R U' R" -> False
"R' F R' B2 R F' R' B2 R2" -> False
```

Comment: What's wrong with `R F2 U3`?

Comment: I just want to make sure, that everybody has the same preconditions. If I would allow `U3`, than you could simply cast the suffix into a digit.

Comment: Why does that matter? Input parsing is not that big a part of the challenge.

Comment: Sure, it doesn't matter a lot, but I want to people to use the original notation, since this is the standard notation (Singmaster notation). Just use the `'`, if that's works with your programming language.

Comment: I'm more used to the notation that uses T-Top, B-Bottom, and P-Posterior (back). People probably just liked seeing the sequence `R2 D2`.

Comment: @mbomb007 I can understand T for top, but I've never seen P for posterior and I wouldn't understand its meaning were it not for your comment...

Comment: The notation is used in an older Rubik's Cube solution book. It's probably 20-30 years old, but that's the only solution book I've ever looked at. I didn't even know about the current notation until I did a project last year on Rubik's Cube for Abstract Algebra.

Comment: @mbomb007 I have seen that notation too, but it is neither as common or as old as the original Singmaster notation, and I don't know why people want to mess with the original. Although David Singmaster (as far as I know) did not mention it, I have observed that all faces are perfectly consistent and with no clashes if considered as directions rather than positions. `That is F(orward), B(ackward), L(eft), R(ight), U(p), D(own)`

Comment: I know the intentions are not such, but currently all test cases will pass even if you do not care about the orientation of the cubies. For example, if a cube is scrambled in such a way that only OLL step is remaining, and I call that cube as identity cube and write by program keeping that in minds, the test cases will still pass. You need to add test cases which dis orient the layers, even though keeping the position correct. For ex. twisted corners, reversed sides etc.

Comment: Good point. I will add some tests, as soon I arrive at home.

Comment: Okay, fine! I'll fix mine!

Comment: Can we swap truthy/falsy output values? For example, if I specify in my answer, can `R2 R2` output `0` and `R2` output `1`?

Comment: @MDXF Yes, I did't explicitly forbid that. But I see that you already found a different way, or can solve the problem in less than 4 bytes without that restriction?

Comment: @Jakube Yes, I found a different way. Swapping truthy/falsy values wouldn't get it below 4 bytes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Haskell, <s>263</s> <s>261</s> <s>247</s> 243 characters

```hs
c[x]=[x]
c(x:"2")=[x,x]
c(x:_)=[x,x,x]
s!a@[x,y,z]=case s of
 'R'|x>0->[x,-z,y]
 'B'|y>0->[z,y,-x]
 'U'|z>0->[-y,x,z]
 'L'|x<0->[x,z,-y]
 'F'|y<0->[-z,y,x]
 'D'|z<0->[y,-x,z]
 _->a
r=[-2..2]
i=mapM id[r,r,r]
f w=i==foldr(map.(!))i(c=<<words w)
```

Rather straightworward algorithm; each cubelet is made out of 1,2,4 or 8 chunks encoding its position and orientation; 4 chunks per edge cubelet, 8 per corner cubelet, 7 cubelets are stationary.

`c` **c**homps each word of the input into a sequence of CW turns, and `!` sends each chunk according to a turn. `i` is the **i**dentity position. `f` is the main **f**unction.

I'm not too happy with the `c`homp function, but I can't seem to find a way to shorten it either (@Nimi did, however)

Comment: How about `c(x:"2")=[x,x]` and `c(x:_)=[x,x,x]`. Saves 2 bytes.

Comment: If you use `i=sequence[s,s,s]`, and change all the tuples to lists (i.e.: `(x,y,z)` becomes `[x,y,z]`) - it'll save ~9 characters. Inlining it saves 4 more. Dropping the `_` case from `!` saves another 11.

Comment: @MtnViewMark done and improved `i`, thanks. Not sure what you mean by inlining `i` - please note it appears twice in the definition for `f`. Not sure what you mean by dropping the `_` case - either leaving `_->a` out completely or moving  it to the top yields a non-exhaustive pattern exception, and moving it to the top doesn't save any characters anyways. I did manage to save 5 characters there, however.

Comment: Great solution. I checked all test cases.

Comment: Again, congrats to your solution. Since you presented the shortest code, you receive the bounty worth 100 reputation.

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubically](//git.io/Cubically), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
¶=8%
```

I win :P

```
¶=8%
¶     read a string, evaluate as Cubically code
 =8   set notepad to (notepad == 8th face)
   %  print notepad
```

The notepad is initialized to zero. The 8th "face" contains 1 if the cube is unsolved and 0 otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P//0DZbC9X//0ONFIIUgtQVQo0A)

Answer (score 3):

### J - <strike>232, 220, 381, 315</strike> 296 bytes

This solution encodes all operations as face permutations and works based on the fact that all face twists are actually the same, under a rotation of the entire cube.

*Edit*: some more golfing

```
f=:+/~6&*
r=:4 :'y f&.>(]{^:x~)&.C.;/i.2 4'"0
t=:((r~0),_4<\44#.inv 1478253772705907911x)&C.&.
Y=:(C.(,0 2 r 4 5),;/4 f&i.8)&{^:t
X=:((,1 1 0 2 r 2 4 3 1)C.C.;/0 4 2 5 f i.8)&{^:t
61".@A."1'=: ',"#~6 3$'D0XR1YF1XU2YB3XL3Y'
T=:[:(_2".@}.'(i.48)-:'&(,,[))[:(,'^:',])/&.>@|.&.;:[:''''&=@{.`]},:&'3'
```

Other than the previous tries, this *does* take corner rotation into account.

`f` is just a helper function. `r` does the rotation of one face. a face is encoded as follows:

1. all corners in steps of 6
2. all edges in steps of six

this order facilitates the encoding of rotations and twists.
`t` is an adverb that twists the face under a certain cube rotation, selecting the face.

`X` and `Y` are adverbs which take as left argument the number of in that direction of the entire cube.

The next line defines all rotations: 3 characters per rotation: the name, the number of rotations and the direction.

The last line defines the test verb `T`, converting 3 and `'` to Power notation, flipping the order of operation appending the test vector andfinally excuting the entire thing.

More details upon request.

```
tests =: (] ;. _2) 0 : 0

 U2 R R' U2
 U D2 U' D2
 U2 R2 R'
 R' U' R' F' U F U' R' F R F' U' R U2 R
 L'
 B B2 B' B2
 D D2 D'
 R F' D2 U B' F2 B' U2 D2 F2 B2 U F R'
 D2 U' R2 U F2 D2 U' R2 U' B' L2 R' B' D2 U B2 L' D' R2
 R U R' U' R' F R2 U' R' U' R U R' F' R2 U R2 U' R2 U' D R2 U' R2 U R2 D'
 R U R' U' R' F R2 U' R' U' R U R' F' R2 U' R2 U R2 U' D R2 U' R2 U R2 D'
 B2 F2 U' F2 U R2 F2 U2 B D' R' D' R2 D' F2 U' F U R2 U R B D B D2 L2 D' F2 U D' R' D B R2 D2 F2 R' F2 D2
 R U2 R' U R' U2 R U2 R U R' U' R' U R U2
 U F B' R' U F' R U' F' B L U' F L'
 R2 U' R' U' R U R U R U' R
 R' F R' B2 R F' R' B2 R2
)
res =: 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
res ([,],:=) T"1 tests NB. passes all tests.
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

NB. some handy display methods:
dispOrig=: (". ;._2) 0 :0
   _   _   _   5  29  11   _   _   _   _   _   _
   _   _   _  47  _1  35   _   _   _   _   _   _
   _   _   _  23  41  17   _   _   _   _   _   _
   3  27   9   0  24   6   1  25   7   2  26   8
  45  _3  33  42  _6  30  43  _5  31  44  _4  32
  21  39  15  18  36  12  19  37  13  20  38  14
   _   _   _   4  28  10   _   _   _   _   _   _
   _   _   _  46  _2  34   _   _   _   _   _   _
   _   _   _  22  40  16   _   _   _   _   _   _
)
ind =: dispOrig i.&, i. 48 NB. indices of i.48 in the original display

disp =: (9 12$(,dispOrig) ind}~ ])
changed =: 1 : '(u ~:&disp ]) i.48' NB. use to debug permutation verbs: L ch
vch =: 1 :'disp  ((]+_*=) u)'
NB. viewmat integration RGB
cm =: 255 * 1 0 0 , 1 1 1, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 1 0.5 0, 0 0 1,: 0 0 0 NB. colormap
NB. use as:  "cube i. 48" for seeing a nice folded out cube.
cube =: cm viewmat (>&7 + >&15 + >&23 + >&31 + >& 39 + >&47)@|@disp@]
```

Comment: "as my test results don't correspond with the ones given ... " as in, your solution doesn't work? I wouldn't post it then...

Comment: You're right. Fixed it now.

Comment: I added 4 additional test cases. Two of them still return the false result. Looks like you ignore the orientation of the corners.

Comment: @jpjacobs There's a 100 rep bounty on the question now. Wanna correct your code?

Comment: Voila, done. Now just reducing it.

Comment: Great job. Sadly your code still is much longer as Jan Dvorak's Haskell solution, therefore I awarded him with the bounty. I really wish, this has more upvotes though.

Comment: No more than fair. Either way, it was one of the better challenges I participated in, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3: 280 chars

This is not a participant in the challenge. Firstly because I asked the challenge myself and secondly because it's not my code. All credits belong to [Stefan Pochmann](http://www.stefan-pochmann.info/), who discovered this awesome way of simulating a Rubik's Cube. I only did some golfing and some minor changes in respect of the challenge.

```
def f(a):
 s=t="UF UR UB UL DF DR DB DL FR FL BR BL UFR URB UBL ULF DRF DFL DLB DBR".split()
 for m in a.split():q="FLBR FRBL FDBU FUBD URDL ULDR".split()['UDLRFB'.index(m[0])];n=2+"2'".find(m[-1]);s=[[p,p.translate(str.maketrans(q,q[n:]+q[:n]))][m[0]in p]for p in s]
 return s==t
```

The idea behind this is the following. `s` represents the location of the pieces of `UF`, `UR`, and so on. For instance: `s = ['DF', 'BL', ...]` means, that the piece `UF` is at the position `DF`, the piece `UR` is at the position `BL`, ...

How does the position of a piece change, when doing a move. If you do a `U`-move, all stickers (colors) of the `U`-layer, which faced the front face, move to the left face. The stickers of the left face move to the back, these to the right and these to the front face. Encoded by `FLBR`. Some examples: `UF` moves to `UL`, `UFR` moves to `ULF` and so on. Therefore, applying a move is simply translating the faces of pieces in the corresponding layer.