# Order of Elements of the Rubik's Cube

Tags: code-golf, math, graph-theory, abstract-algebra, rubiks-cube

#### Introduction

All the possible moves and their combinations of a Rubik's Cube form a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)). A group in general is a set with some binary operation defined on it. It must contain a neutral element with respect to this operator as well as inverses for every element of the set. For instance the integers \$\mathbb Z\$ with the addition \$+\$ forms a group. In the case of the Rubik's Cube it is a *finite* group as there are only about \$4.3 \cdot 10^{19} \$ distinct moves. This implies that any move has a finite [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)), this means that if you repeat any move enough times, you will end up back at the original state that the cube had when you started applying those moves.

#### Challenge

Given some move on the Rubik's Cube, determine how many times you have to repeat that move until you get to the original state (i.e. find the *order* of that move).

#### Details

- We are using the \$3\times 3\times 3\$ Rubik's Cube.
- There are 12 elementary moves: Each of those turns the front, back, left, right, up or down layer by 90°. The clockwise moves are denoted by the corresponding letters `F,B,L,R,U,D`. The counterclockwise elementary moves are denoted by the same letters followed by an apostrophe, for instance `F'` denotes a counter clockwise rotation of 90° of the front layer. If you want, you can also use a lower case letter `f` instead.
- We write all non elementary moves a sequence of elementary moves, these are written as a string and read from left to right. As an example `FFU'` denotes a clockwise rotation of 180° of the front layer followed by a counterclockwise rotation of the top layer. Similarly `FFF = F'`.
- The order of the Rubik's Cube group is $$43'252'003'274'489'856'000 = 2^{27}\cdot 3^{14}\cdot 5^3\cdot 7^2\cdot 11.$$ [Lagrange's theroem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) says that for any element of a finte group, the order of that element must divide the order of that group. So your submission must necessarily output a divisor of the number above. In fact the element with the greatest order in the Rubik's Cube group has only an order of \$1260 = 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7\$.

## Examples

Thanks @KevinCruijssen for verifying:

```
Move     Order
(empty)             1
F                   4
FF                  2
FFFF                1
U'L'              105
LLUU                6
L'L'U'             30
RUUD'BD'         1260
U'L'U'LU'L'U'U'L    4
R'LFRL'U'           5
```